# OneClick installer runs properly only on a computer with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, deployment, dll, pinvoke

My Visual Studio solution has four projects, each of them with few dependencies. One of the projects, LSA.Framework, has references to external libraries and those libraries use some file dependencies. Furthermore this project contains the **DllImport** attribute in order to use a function from a C++ project (again in the solution). I have added all of the dependencies as project files (with the content option).

When I create the OneClick installer everything works great. However if I install it on a computer without Visual Studio the program freezes when it has to execute code via DllImport I believe. Any ideas what might cause the problem?

Comment: Is the external dll marked as "copy to output directory" ?

Comment: For however encounters the same problem - I found the solution. First you have to make sure you compile for Release, second all the projects have to be compiled for the same architecture. Finally compile for x86, otherwise you could experience problems somewhere...

Comment: The thing was that the installer was not adding vc++ redistributable.